# Formatting of \bigwedge in display math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I posted an answer on math.se  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/211489/38268) and in there I used double dollar mode. Now in that mode, I had

```
\bigwedge^ \hspace{1mm} k V
```

but upon rendering it looks weird like

[image]

How can I bring the `k` closer to the big wedge so that it looks more normal like in single dollar mode? In single dollar mode, we have `$\bigwedge^k V$` looking a lot more natural.

Comment: Does this concern a document printed with TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt or just MathJax?

Comment: @egreg I am not sure, on math.se it is printed with MathJax but when I type up latex documents I get the same problem too, so it's probably a latex wide problem.

Comment: You should *never* use `$$` in LaTeX; probably `\[\bigwedge\nolimits^{\!k}V\]` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @egreg Ahhh that works in gedit for me! However, in math.se I have to use ``$$`` as ``\[ ..\]`` does not work.

Comment: Recall that MathJax (used in Math.SE) is *not* LaTeX, while it uses some of its conventions.

Comment: @egreg What's the difference between double dollar and ``\[..\]``?

Comment: @BenjaLim: See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Comment: @egreg Grazie. Thanks for your help! Now I'll change from double dollar.

Comment: nobody has mentioned that in your example, you have a positive value for `\hspace` which would push the `^k` away from the wedge.  but this shouldn't work anyhow, since the superscript, which consists of multiple parts (the `\hspace` and the `k`) needs to be wrapped in braces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Choose one among the following inputs, in LaTeX:

```
\[
\bigwedge^k V
\]

\[
\bigwedge\nolimits^k V
\]

\[
\bigwedge\nolimits^{\!k} V
\]
```

The respective results are shown below

[image]

The first is widely used, the second appears faulty. The command `\!` inserts a small backspacing.

Why not using `$$` in LaTeX is explained here: [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Answer (score 3):

did you try the following?

```
\newcommand{\mybigwedge}[1]{\bigwedge^{\kern{-3pt}#1}}
```

(where the -3 can be fine tuned to your taste)

Comment: I get error "illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)"